# Could not get unknown property 'srcDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

При попытке открыть GDX-проект, мне пишется: Could not get unknown property 'srcDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput
Что делать?

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
```

Comment: Это значит, что у вас в gradle не правильно указан путь до `srcDir`

Comment: где у вас `srcDir: ${some path to your file}`?

Comment: @Dred, а где он должен быть? И какой файл должен быть?

Comment: Это вам виднее, ваш проект. Сделайте полный поиск внутри вашего проекта по слову `srcDir`